# List of all the users that logged in using GUI or Command Line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ubuntu-12.04

I need to calculate the total time that a specific user stay logged in per day. And stop user using the computer more than the time allowed by shutting down the system.

`uptime` cannot be used since this is a multiuser computer

`last` command is not doing the job, because, as I observed, it only store data of users who run the terminal. If a user logged in using GUI and continue to use the computer without running the terminal an entry is **not** written to /var/log/wtmp.

Is there a way to find the information I need?
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: How long do you want to allow? Minutes? Hours?

Comment: You say this is a multiuser computer, wouldn't it be bad for other users when the computer gets shut down if _any_ other user exceeds his daily limit?

Comment: @mpy- OK 'multiuser' should not be taken in pure technical meaning with relate to mainframes etc. This is more for things like parental control. Plan is to check the username and shutdown if someone spending too much time on the computer :)

Comment: @terdon Lets say 1 hour for now

Comment: Check out Unix process accounting: The `ac` commands can show you login duration per user and day. On OS X, today's output looks like this for me: `May 30  total       21.56`

Answer (score 4):

`who` (using `/var/run/utmp`) should work if the user is logged in via X, too.

Then you can run this script via `/etc/crontab` *every minute*. What it does:

- loop over all users (`$u`) currently logged in
- increments the number in `/var/log/accounting-$u` -- as this is done every minute, the file stores the total time the user `$u` is logged in so far.
- check if `$u` has reached the limit (`$allowedtime`), here 60 minutes. If so, shutdown the system or whatever. 5 minutes earlier only send a warning (courtesy of @terdon).
- finally if the user `$u` wasn't seen for the last 24 hours, delete `/var/log/accounting-$u` and the game can start from the beginning.

As I mentioned in a comment, I don't think shutting down the system is not such a good idea. Especially with this script, because if a user logs in again while the 24 hours aren't over yet, the shutdown action will be triggered after less than a minute (when the cron starts `accounting.sh` the next time).

---

**accounting.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

accountinglogprefix=/var/log/accounting-
allowedtime=60

for u in $(who | cut -d " " -f 1 | sort | uniq); do

  if [[ -e ${accountinglogprefix}${u} ]]; then
    consumed=$(cat ${accountinglogprefix}${u})
  else
    consumed=0
  fi
  echo -n $(( consumed + 1 )) > ${accountinglogprefix}${u}

  if [[ $consumed -gt $allowedtime ]]; then 
    # time is over, do whatever you want
    echo "Shutting down..."
  elif [[ $consumed -gt $(( allowedtime - 5 )) ]]; then
    # notify the user $u that his time is over in 5 minutes with a suitable command
    echo "Time's up! Shutting down in 5 minutes..."
  fi

  # check if e.g. 24h have passed since the user was last seen
  if [[ $(( $(date +%s ) - $(stat -c %Y ${accountinglogprefix}${u}) )) -gt $(( 24 * 3600 )) ]]; then
    rm ${accountinglogprefix}${u}
  fi

done
```

**Note:** This is not a fully mature script (i.e. ready for copy & paste) -- it should just demonstrate a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than writing custom scripts one could use software available and designed to do exactly that and more.

please check if `psacct` is available for you to install.

From: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html

> The psacct package contains several utilities for monitoring process
>   activities, including ac, lastcomm, accton and sa.
>
> ```
> The ac command displays statistics about how long users have been logged on.
> The lastcomm command displays information about previous executed commands.
> The accton command turns process accounting on or off.
> The sa command summarizes information about previously executed commmands.
> ```

Comment: +1 for a wheel unreinvented. The Ubuntu install is `sudo apt-get install acct` (and `sudo service acct start`).

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to parse the output of `ps`:

```
$ ps -U terdon -u terdon -o %t 
  ELAPSED
  00:39
  00:06
```

In this example, user `terdon` is running two processes, the oldest of which has been running for 39 seconds. So, if you parse this to get the longest running process (probably the user's login shell), you can tell how long the user has been logged in. In this example, I will assume you want to allow at least a full hour (that's why I use `NF>=3` in the `gawk` command) but no more than 4:

```
ps -U terdon -u terdon -o %t | grep : | sed 's/ *//g' | 
   gawk -F"[ +:]" 'NF>=3{print $1}' | sort -g | tail -n 1
```

This command will print the elapsed **hours** of user terdon's longest running command. You can now check if that is more or less than 4:

```
limit=4;
time=$(ps -U terdon -u terdon -o %t |  grep : | sed 's/ *//g' | 
        gawk -F"[ +:]" 'NF>=3{print $1}' | sort -g | tail -n 1);
 if [[ $time -gt 3 ]]; 
 then echo "Time's up! Shutting down in 5 minutes...";
      shutdown -h +5
fi
```

Comment: But you could easily "hack" this by logging out and immediately logging in again when you get the "Time's up message"?!

Comment: Well, yes but that would be dishonest!

Comment: how about writing the time already spent to a file periodically or when user is logging out and reading that file when logging in next time

Comment: Yes, see @mpy's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can audit your secure log. It's located in:

> /var/log/secure

It gives you logins and logouts. Also you can run logwatch and it will give you who logged in for the period you run it for.

Here is some more information too:

**1. Retrieve all successful logins on the system**

> cat /var/log/secure* | grep Accepted > logins.txt

Now logins.txt will contain all successfull logins to you Redhat linux system.
You may go through the file and have a manual first look up.

**2. Check users at perticular time**

Other command to find out last login details of perticular users we have *last, lastb* commands which shows listing of last logged in users.

The last program, which prints a detailed report of the times of the most recent user logins, does so by scanning the /var/log/wtmp file.

*Output includes following details:*

```
Username
Tty device number
Login date and time
Logout time
Total working time
```

It also has an option to search logins at perticular time as follows:
last -t YYYYMMDDHHMMSS – Display the state of logins as of the specified time.

Files used in this are:
/etc/utmp – This is a binary file that contains a record for every active tty line.
/var/adm/wtmp – Keeps track of both logins and logouts.

Comment: There is no 'secure' file or folder in /var/log/. Is it part of logwatch?

Comment: last command is not working for me - I explained my scenario in the question

Comment: You'll probably need to install it: sudo apt-get last* Here is the man page for it in Ubuntu: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/last.1.html

Comment: The secure data may be in system.log, messages or possibly auth.log. Sorry I run Fedora and it's slightly different.

Comment: Ubuntu log file breakouts: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles

Comment: last command is already installed but it does not store the information I need. If the user ran the terminal (command prompt) then I can see username in the list generated by last command. Otherwise username is not shown in the list.
I'll try the other approach thanks